# In a Microsoft Flow, how do you specify the Destination File Path when copying a file from OneDrive to a SharePoint document library folder?

Tags: onedrive-for-business, flow

I like to work on files in OneDrive. A subset of these need to be published, whenever they're edited, to a SharePoint Online document library. I've started a Flow to handle this. Using the OneDrive "When A File is Modified" trigger and the SharePoint Copy action. But I can't get the destination path right. When I do a test run, I get "Flow Run Failed." The error is "Bad Request." Status code is 400.

Comment: what variations have you tried?

Comment: Several iterations of /path/to/file and URL.

Comment: Have you tried server-relative? /sites/site/shared documents/folder/mydoc.docx

Comment: Yes. I've tried relative and absolute paths. Same result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Create File" action like this

Flow will be like this:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Regards,
Chandani Prajapati

Comment: Can you please tell me how to create a copy of a file and add timestamp to file name, ie `/my_backups/my_file_name_bak_ddmmyyyy_hhmmss.xlsx`?